# wondering on a alternative approach to ajax .load when loading a lot of data to different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello in my continued journey to learning some html & jquery stuff by trying to replicate some monitoring systems (SCADA) to a web based system, I stumbled upon openseadragon to use as MAP system similar to google maps and using its overlays, I was able to setup a candidate to replace a system where basic on/off monitors where presented on a map.

to do this, I just created a simple php file that parses the current status from a database, and just outputs a simple div with  Online  for On, and  Offline  for Off, pretty simple stuff, and by just adding something like to the php file like status.php?loc=16, I was able to get the status per location.

Now I just use ajax setInterval, and just attach a simple $.load and point it to different id's scattered on the map (rendered as overlays by openseadragon), I'm currently at 51 points, and all seems well, so technically I have 51 $.load calls in a setInterval set for 5 seconds, I'm wondering if there is cleaner approach to this, I will be definitely approaching 100 divs, so that would be 100 calls. and at that point I'm not sure what the behavior would be, wouldn't be surprised if I crash the browser in the process,lol

It's just a thought, I've been reading around about JSON, might look into that, im just not sure how to handle the multiple divs at the moment.

this is how it looks by the way

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
setInterval(function() {
    $('#pt1').load('status.php?loc=1');
    $('#pt2').load('status.php?loc=2');
    $('#pt3').load('status.php?loc=3');
    // .
    // . up to
    // .
    $('#pt99').load('status.php?loc=99');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this:

```
var callWorker = function(val){
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#pt1').load('status.php?loc=' + val);
    }, 3000);
}

for(var i = 100; i--;){
    callWorker(i);
}
```